# Verify if an Open Graph action with a url was already made

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app on Facebook for automatic social reading for a newspaper and I have no idea how to verify if a action was already made by a user, i.e. every page on the newspaper website read by a user is automatically shared at Facebook with a non-built-in action type.

I tried something like:

```
me/[action type]:[?article=[readed url article]
```

But i didn't have any success because it returned all the posts associated with the action type.

How can I search in the Graph for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see which actions the user has already performed by querying the Graph API as follows:
`http://graph.facebook.com/me/{action_id}`. This will return all the articles the user has read for the particular action.

Use the list and cross reference it with the articles to determine which articles were previously read. I.e. match the `$activity['data']['article']['url']` with the `$url` of the article (where `$activity` is the data returned by the above Graph API call).

Comment: the problem is make the search at mine js. should have a search at facebook-side. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do this using the API only. You will have to save this information either

- as the action was taken, when you receive the action id as the response and save to a database or,
- Loop through the call you have in the language of your app and check programmatically whether the object was discovered by the user already

Comment: really? that's look a little bit strange... but, ok, i'll do that. thanks!